# Parsing series of strings from a received SMS in GSM modem using Arduino

Tags: regex, string, parsing, arduino, gsm

I'm trying to reply from a received SMS in a gsm modem.

The problem is, I don't know how to extract the phone number from this series of strings so I could get the number of the sender.

I must extract the sender's number, "09279127639".

```
+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","09279127639","","13/04/05,08:24:36+22"
```

Note: The sender's number is varying. This is only an example.

After extracting, I want it to return its value into this codes so I could reply to him automatically.

```
void setup()
{ pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
delay(3000);
digitalWrite(8, LOW);

Serial.begin(9600);
Serial1.begin(9600); //Baud rate of the GSM/GPRS Module 
Serial.print("\r");
Serial1.print("\r");
delay(1000); 

Serial1.print("AT\r");
Serial.print("AT\r");
delay(10000); 
Serial1.print("AT\r");
Serial.print("AT\r");
delay(1000); 

Serial1.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
Serial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
delay(1000);

Serial1.print("AT+CMGS=\"number here\"\r");
Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"number here\"\r"); //Number to which you want to send the sms
delay(1000);

Serial1.print("This is a message from a GSM modem.\r");
Serial.print("This is a message from a GSM modem.\r"); //The text of the message to be sent
delay(1000);

Serial1.write(0x1A);
Serial.write(0x1A);
delay(1000); 
}
void loop()
{
}
```

Your reply will be fully appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequel to my last answer, add

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

The regex helps you cut them into desired pieces. Create a class name ShortMessage.cs and create properties from variables like this

```
 #region Private Variables
    private string index;
    private string status;
    private string sender;
    private string alphabet;
    private string sent;
    private string message;
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    public string Index
    {
        get { return index; }
        set { index = value; }
    }
    public string Status
    {
        get { return status; }
        set { status = value; }
    }
    public string Sender
    {
        get { return sender; }
        set { sender = value; }
    }
    public string Alphabet
    {
        get { return alphabet; }
        set { alphabet = value; }
    }
    public string Sent
    {
        get { return sent; }
        set { sent = value; }
    }
    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set { message = value; }
    }
    #endregion
```

With this method, you can always get the sender's phone numbers and messages cleanly.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this. What library should I use for this?

Comment: Just call regularexpression. Using System.Text.Regularexpression;

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the split method

```
String s = string.Empty;
        s = "REC READ","09279127639","","13/04/05,08:24:36+22";
        string[] str = s.Split(',');
        foreach (string mem in str)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mem);
        }
```

Comment: How about if another number send an SMS? the sender is varying.. I need a code that will work for any 11 digit numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{11}");// matching 11 digit number, or [0-9]
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
```

Cheers

Comment: The length of the phone number may not be known.

Comment: Serial.print("AT+CMGS=\"number here\"\r"); //Number to which you want to send the sms
delay(1000);

How will I input the extracted number to this code?

Answer (score -1):

Why not read it and use regularexpression to distinguish it

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");
                Match m = r.Match(input);
                while (m.Success)
                {
                    ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                    //msg.Index = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
                    msg.Index = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    msg.Status = m.Groups[2].Value;
                    msg.Sender = m.Groups[3].Value;
                    msg.Alphabet = m.Groups[4].Value;
                    msg.Sent = m.Groups[5].Value;
                    msg.Message = m.Groups[6].Value;
                    #region PROCESS DATA
                    string[] p_str = { msg.Index + " (Index) ", msg.Status + " (Status) ", msg.Sender + " (Sender) ", msg.Alphabet + " (Alphabet) ", msg.Sent + " (Sent Date) ", msg.Message + " (Message) " };
                    ProcessData(p_str);
                    #endregion
                    m = m.NextMatch();
                }
```

The ShortMessage should be a class that has these structures. It worked for me

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this. So, to use the number of the sender, I must use the **msg.Sender**? Am i right?

Comment: What are the libraries should I use? What is the library for regex?

Comment: Yes, with msg.Sender, you can always know the sender's phone number.

Comment: I see this is incredibly old, but when I try this regex method I get the message "'Regex' was not declared in this scope" - I'm guessing I'm missing something.